# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error in parsing JSON data

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, indexoutofboundsexception

I am getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException at `id[i] = c.getString(TAG_ID);`

Here's the code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
    JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);
    id[i] = c.getString(TAG_ID);
}
```

I have checked that JSON file contains 25 objects. I have also tried using `i<10` but it still gives same error.

Comment: What is `id` declared as?

Comment: Id is an array ? What is the size of it?

Comment: pls post logcat error log ...

Comment: thanks but timrau's answer did it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`id` should be an array with at least 25 elements to avoid index out-of-bound.

```
String [] id = new String[25];
```

Answer (score 2):

Initialize id[] array equivalent to loop condition before entering the for loop.

Or

Add null check to array id[] size inside the for loop and Initialize array equivalent to loop condition.

Answer (score 1):

You declared your id array as -

```
String id[] = {null};
```

That is size of your id array is 1. When you are trying to access 25th or 10th array you are getting the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException`.

Redefining your `id` array may help you -

```
String[] id = new String[25];
```

Or better you may use `ArrayList` then you don't have to think about the size of the array -

```
List<String> id = new ArrayList<String>(); //declaration of id ArrayList
```

Then in your for loop you may do this -

```
for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
    JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);
    id.add(c.getString(TAG_ID));
}
```

Hope it will Help.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: It gives error as **Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to String[]**

Comment: did you meant String id[]=new String[25];?